# Filter the Collection I get with Spatie Laravel Google Calendar

Tags: collections, laravel-5

I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar to retrieve Events form a Google Calendar: I can get the events and paginate them like this:

```
$events = Event::get();
$page = Input::get('page', 1); // Get the ?page=1 from the url
$perPage = 10; // Number of items per page
$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

$records = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_slice($events->toArray(), $offset, $perPage, true), // Only grab the items we need
    count($events), // Total items
    $perPage, // Items per page
    $page, // Current page
    ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()]
);
```

So far so good.

Now I'd like to filter these Events based on some parameters in a search form:

1. get all the Events where startDateTime is between a given start date and a given end date (I can set them in my search form)
2. get all the Events where name contains a given string

So, i.e., my search form can provide a start date of "2016-11-26", an end date of "2016-12-08" and a search term like "reunion", and I need to retrieve the filtered data

Since I have no database (Events are retrieved from Google Calendar) this is much difficult to me

Any help, please?

Comment: Did you had any luck with this? I am also trying to do the same. Filtering events based on information or etag. Can you help?